# Ruby: define function prototypes?

Tags: ruby

It is possible to define a prototype of a function or in some way indicate to Ruby that a function exists even though it may not be defined yet?

I have lots of classes like this:

```
class Program 
  FIRST  = Block.FIRST
  FOLLOW = Set.new['$']
end

class Block
  FIRST  = Declaration.FIRST
  FOLLOW = Set.new['.'] 
end

class Declaration
  FIRST  = ConstDecl.FIRST + VarDecl.FIRST + ProcDecl.FIRST
end

class ConstDecl
  FIRST = Set.new['const'] + EMPTY_SET
end
```

Which as you can see reference fields from classes that are defined below them, Is there a way to indicate to Ruby that these classes exist, and ask Ruby to look for them?

Comment: You're permanently assigning values that are not available. What do you expect to happen? The variables to have some Schroedinger state? This looks like a design problem rather than a programming problem to me.

Comment: I know that the values aren't available by default, because obviously nothing exists after the current execution point in an interpreted program. I was asking for any ways I could indicate that the definitions were below, like in C or C++ where I could define a function prototype.

Comment: In C something like that is possible because there exist pointers and the concept of declarations. In Ruby, no pointers and no declarations exist, so forward declaration is not possible (and not sensible either). If you provide more about the context of these constants, we might help you better. Chances are that you should use objects and methods for this instead of class constants (which are more of a C thing as well).

Comment: @NiklasB. Well basically FIRST and FOLLOW are two sets I am going to using to handle errors while parsing the syntax of some language. They define the set of symbols you FIRST encounter in that production and the set of symbols that FOLLOW that production. I was hoping to be able to define them all globally, so when I try to enter my error procedure I can just do this: `error("program", Program.FOLLOW)`

Comment: There appear to be no circular dependencies, can't you just define them in reverse order?

Comment: The FOLLOW set is processed top-down and the FIRST set is processed bottom-up, so if I reversed the order for the FIRST set to compile, I would then mess up the order for the FOLLOW set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is something like this:

```
class Program
  def self.first;   Block.first  end
  def self.follow;  Set.new['$'] end
end

class Block
  def self.first;   Declaration.first end
  def self.follow;  Set.new['.']      end
end

class Declaration
  def self.first;   ConstDecl.first + VarDecl.first + ProcDecl.first end
end

class ConstDecl
  def self.first;   Set.new['const'] + EMPTY_SET end
end
```

This doesn't seem like good design to me, though, I'd probably make those objects instead of classes and use a proper type hierarchy.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to design them as objects to me, the data they represent are productions, which only have a single definition. Thank you for this though it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A major difference between Ruby and other languages which you may be accustomed to (like C/C++) is that before execution, a C/C++ program is processed by a compiler which matches up uses of variables/functions to their definitions. Ruby programs are simply executed from top to bottom, one statement at a time. So when a line which references `Block.FIRST` is executed, the Ruby interpreter can't "look forward" in the program code and see what value will be assigned to `Block.FIRST` later. It knows nothing about what will come later; it only knows what it has executed so far.

Perhaps one of the strongest characteristics of Ruby is that almost *everything* is dynamic and can be changed at run-time. If you are coming from a C/C++ background, this is the first thing you need to get your head around to understand Ruby. For example, constants in Ruby can be assigned conditionally:

```
class Block
  if rand % 2 == 0
    FIRST = '.'
  else
    FIRST = '$'
  end
end
```

If the Ruby interpreter was required to "look forward" to see what the value of `Block.FIRST` should be, what should it predict in the above case?

This is a conceptual shift from what you are used to, and it will require you to structure your programs in a different way, and *think about* your programs in a different way. If you try to write C/C++/Java in Ruby, you will be fighting all the way.

In this case, I recommend you simply reverse the order of your definitions and go "bottom-up". There are other ways to achieve the same effect, but that is the simplest one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I have come to find that Ruby is much different than the mindset I use to program in Java/C++/C. Sometimes it is almost too dynamic for me. My initial solution to this was something that you suggested where I could just define things bottom-up and have things below depend on them, but with this is representing data for a grammar which has cyclical dependencies so that solution never stuck. I am still using a solution similar to the one suggested by Niklas.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: When you come from a more "static" language to Ruby, you may feel at first that you are on a roller-coaster with no seatbelt. No compiler checking, no static analysis tools... then when you get used to bending and twisting the language like rubber, and you go back to your previous "static" language, you will feel like you are strapped very tight into a chair, so you can hardly move. You may swing back and forth between thinking this one is better and then thinking that one is better, then eventually settle in the middle and just use each for what it is best suited for.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `defined?(function_name)`

Comment: Just note that newcomers to SO cannot comment until a certain rep point but they can answer.